# error TS2322: Type 'IHotel | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IHotel'

Tags: angularjs

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

**src/app/hotel-list/hotel-detail/hotel-detail.component.ts:24:7 - error TS2322: Type 'IHotel | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IHotel'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IHotel'.**

```
this.hotel = hotels.find(hotel => hotel.hotelId == id);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct way to write that line

```
ngOnInit(): void {
const id: number= +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;

this.hotelService.getHotels().subscribe((hotels: IHotel[]) => {
  this.hotel=hotels.find((hotel:IHotel)=> hotel.hotelId === id)!;
  console.log('hotel: ', this.hotel);
});
```